# installing PHP 5.4 or higher with sqlsrv on Win 2003 server

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have to upgrade an application that is installed on a win 2003 server from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4 or higher. The datacenter tell us to keep OS untouched if possible.

The sqlsrv driver is acusing the following error, that is a common issue when installing sqlsrv dll:

```
Erro -49
This extension requires the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
Erro 0
```

The question is that ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server apparently is only available on win 2008 server or higher, as described on the link above.

Is there any solution to upgrade PHP on this server and replace mssql extension to sqlsrv under the current OS (win 2003)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems like an answer is **no**. According to [official system requirements docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx), on Windows 2003 is currently supported only sqlsrv version 2.0 and it's only for PHP 5.2/5.3. I think this kind of version support is nothing new in Microsoft world.